# how can i make R count some names once since they are duplicated

Tags: r, database

I have a database with a lot of values and a lot of them are duplicates since they are the same game but in a different platform.

I want R to count names that are duplicate like gta V, gta IV etc. once, because when I try to do a top 10 chart, I get those names a couple of times since they released for multiple platforms. My code looks like this:

```
top_10 <- ign %>%
  arrange(desc(score)) %>%
  slice(1:10)

ggplot(top_10, aes(x=title, y=score))+
  geom_col(fill="blue")+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size=10, angle = 90))+
  ylab("score")+ 
  xlab("title")+
  labs(title = "Top 10 Best Games")
```

When you press enter, the chart doesn't pick 10 different ones, it only picks the first 10 and some of them have the same name. So instead of a top 10, it looks more like a top 5:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO - could you please update your question with some sample data? `dput(head(ign))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is with the limitations of the dataset, and not your code. The data you have does not lend itself to selecting the top 10 across all platforms as the score values are not unique. In other words, you cannot select the "top 10 greatest games of all time" because the score column does not rank them best to worst, only a score out of 10. So when you `slice()` the df, you will only get the first 10 rows with a value of 10. Perhaps a more logical approach is to `slice()` the top 10 by each individual platform value instead.

Using [this dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/joebeachcapital/ign-games?resource=download), here are some possible ways to plot your data. Note that there are some duplicated records in the ign dataset that are the same apart from their X column value, this code removes the duplicates:

**Data and required packages**

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(stringr)

# Import previously downloaded data into R
ign <- read.csv("ign.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# Get top 10 games per platform, remove duplicate rows
# and add xorder column for plot order
top_10 <- ign %>%
  group_by_at(vars(-X)) %>% 
  filter(n() == 1) %>%
  select(title, score, platform) %>%
  arrange(desc(score)) %>%
  group_by(platform) %>%
  slice(1:10) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(xorder = 1:n())
```

**Method 1: Plot top 10 for single platform e.g. Android**

```
# Plot top 10 for single platform
ggplot(filter(top_10, platform == "Android"),
       aes(x = xorder, y = score, fill = platform)) +
  geom_col() +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = top_10$xorder,
                     labels = top_10$title) +
  labs(title = "Top 10 Best Android Games",
       x = "title",
       y = "score") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size = 12, angle = 90, hjust = 1, vjust = 0.5),
        legend.position = "none",
        plot.title = element_text(size = 40))
```

[image: result1]

**Method 2: Plot multiple platforms e.g. all PlayStation versions**

```
# Plot top 10 games for platform/s that start with "Play" e.g. all "PlayStation
ggplot(filter(top_10, str_detect(platform, "^Play")),
       aes(x = factor(xorder), y = score, fill = platform)) +
  geom_col() +
  scale_x_discrete(breaks = top_10$xorder,
                  labels = top_10$title) +
  labs(title = "Top 10 Best PlayStation Platform Games",
       x = "title",
       y = "score") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size = 12, angle = 90, hjust = 1, vjust = 0.5),
        plot.title = element_text(size = 40))
```

[image: result2]